# How to set relationship between two tables in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have got two tables:

1. Announcements
2. AnnouncementsSchedule

Relationship is `one(Announcements)` to `many(AnnouncementsSchedule)` by keys:

```
Announcements.id = AnnouncementsSchedule.announcements_id
```

I tried to describe models in SQLAlchemy:

The first table is described as model:

```
class Announcements(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'announcements'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    subcategory = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    offer_type = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    #children = relationship("AnnouncementsSchedule", back_populates="announcements")
```

Second is:

```
class AnnouncementsSchedule(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'announcements_schedule'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    week_day = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=True)
    week_all = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    time = db.Column(db.Time(), nullable=False)
    announcement_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('announcements.announcements_id'))
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Did you an get error? What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in the column name (announcements doesn't have **announcement_id** ):

```
# announcement_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('announcements.announcements_id'))
# change to ->
announcement_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('announcements.id'))
```

Comment: Thank you, then how to get data from related table?

Comment: announcement = relationship("Announcements", back_populates="schedules") -- on the first model, put ->  schedules = relationship("AnnouncementsSchedule", back_populates="announcement")